# Why does Mapbox give error "bounds south value must be between -95 and 95"

Tags: upload, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I got this error because I had my longitude and latitude values switched in my data source.

However, I thought that valid ranges should be between -90 and +90 for latitude and between -180 and +180 for longitude.

Why use -95/95 values for the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original report is here: https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive/issues/113

How to solve this kind of problems (given I found it from scratch and am not familiar with mapbox source code):

1. Google for the exact error message: `"bounds south value must be between -95 and 95"` (with double quotes for the exact matches only)
2. The bottom result refers to https://coveralls.io/files/925478894
3. It gives the name, google it: `mapbox tilelive`
4. Find there is a https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive
5. Open the file known from item #2 https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive/blob/master/lib/tilelive.js
6. Push `blame` button: https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive/blame/master/lib/tilelive.js
7. ctrl+f `-95` and see the commit it was done at: https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive/commit/ac1298694a5e76f40cb8effdb229b160ec4ef4e5
8. The commit refers to the original issue https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive/issues/113

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer is very helpful way beyond the original problem!