# latitude must be between -90 and 90 but was -122.419415

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I am having the wierdest thing happening with my map.
I am getting the bound of the camera to get northeast and southwest coordinates to generate a geohash to then get points loaded depending on where I look on the map.

This works great for Europe but when moving the map over USA I get the following error:

```
ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error, java.lang.Error: latitude must be between -90 and 90 but was -122.419415, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Error: latitude must be between -90 and 90 but was -122.419415
```

And yes the error tells me the issue but I don't get how to fix it?
I have tried to flip the coordinates to see if that helped but that did not work.

What I am doing now is getting the getCameraState to get the center of the camera. Then I take that result and push it into the coordinateBoundsZoomForCamera.

Here is my code for the whole process. I am missing something or am I doing it wrong.

```
mapboxMap?.getCameraState().then((value) {
  var latitude = "";
  var longitude = "";
  var centerCoordinates = value.center.entries.first;
  var centerCoordinatesAsString = centerCoordinates.value.toString();
  var result = centerCoordinatesAsString.substring(
      1, centerCoordinatesAsString.length - 1);
  List<dynamic> listCoordinates = result.split(",");
  latitude = listCoordinates[0].toString().trim();
  longitude = listCoordinates[1].toString().trim();

  mapboxMap
      ?.coordinateBoundsZoomForCamera(CameraOptions(
    center: Point(
        coordinates: Position(
      num.parse(longitude), 
      num.parse(latitude), // Crash happens here
    )).toJson(),
  ))
      .then((value) async {
    var north = value.bounds.northeast["coordinates"];
    var south = value.bounds.southwest["coordinates"];
```

Did take a look at this question: [Why does Mapbox give error "bounds south value must be between -95 and 95"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762455/why-does-mapbox-give-error-bounds-south-value-must-be-between-95-and-95) but not much help.

Comment: it is referring your value is out of range, you can compare and set the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will prevent the crash, but you may check the source of `listCoordinates` getting data.

```dart
double lat = num.tryParse(latitude)?? 0;

lat = lat<=-90? -90 : lat;
lat = lat>=90? 90:lat;

...
 center: Point(
        coordinates: Position(
      num.parse(longitude), // can be same here
      lat,
```